# List of swagger UI alternatives

Tags: swagger-ui

Is there any Swagger UI alternatives ? I already know:

- http://swaggerui.herokuapp.com/#!/pet/addPet
- http://public.redfroggy.fr/swagger2

Answer (score 131):

Yes, there are a few of them.

- [ReDoc](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc) [[Article on swagger.io]](http://swagger.io/redoc-openapi-powered-documentation/) [[GitHub]](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc) [[demo]](http://rebilly.github.io/ReDoc/) - Reinvented OpenAPI/Swagger-generated API Reference Documentation (I'm the author)
- OpenAPI GUI [[GitHub]](https://github.com/Mermade/openapi-gui) [[demo]](https://mermade.github.io/openapi-gui/) - GUI / visual editor for creating and editing OpenApi / Swagger definitions *(has OpenAPI 3 support)*
- Responsive Fork of SwaggerUI [[GitHub]](https://github.com/jensoleg/swagger-ui) [[demo]](http://swaggerui.herokuapp.com/?url=http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json#!/pet/addPet)
- SwaggerUI-Angular [[GitHub]](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/angular-swagger-ui) [[demo]](http://orange-opensource.github.io/angular-swagger-ui) - An angularJS implementation of Swagger UI
- angular-swagger-ui-material [[GitHub]](https://github.com/darosh/angular-swagger-ui-material) [[demo]](http://darosh.github.io/angular-swagger-ui-material/) - Material Design template for angular-swager-ui

### Hosted solutions that support swagger:

- [Apiary](http://docs.pandurangpatil.apiary.io/#) - can import from swagger
- [Readme.io](https://sample-threes.readme.io/docs) - can import from swagger
- [Lucybot console](https://developer.kaltura.com/api-docs/) - supports swagger natively
- [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/api_documentation/intro_to_api_documentation) - can import from swagger
- [Stoplight](https://stoplight.io) - supports swagger natively - editing and reading

### Check the following articles for more details:

- [Ultimate Guide to 30+ API Documentation Solutions](http://nordicapis.com/ultimate-guide-to-30-api-documentation-solutions/)
- [Turning Contracts into Beautiful Documentation](https://blog.apisyouwonthate.com/turning-contracts-into-beautiful-documentation-deac7013af18) (focused mainly on Swagger)
- [An evaluation of auto-generated REST API Documentation UIs](https://dotdev.co/an-evaluation-of-auto-generated-rest-api-documentation-uis-53031753a789#.vv4nyxyza) (focused mainly on Swagger)
- [Free and Open Source API Documentation Tools](https://pronovix.com/blog/free-and-open-source-api-documentation-tools?platform=hootsuite)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that LucyBot is self-hosted.

Comment: I came across a few interesting free ones - http://www.apicur.io/, https://apibldr.com, http://www.apicur.io/. The first one looks great. Could be helpful

Comment: Do you happen to know which is the smallest? I'm looking for a lightweight alternative to swagger-ui to use on embedded devices.

Comment: It looks like 'Responsive Fork of SwaggerUI [GitHub] [demo]' is a dead project. Should we edit to reflect that?