# how to change swagger-ui layout

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, jira-rest-api

I use swagger-ui as my api doc tool, but the layout I want is the window split left and right, The left show all tags and api endpoint and the right show api operation. When I click the endpoint on the left, the right side add a new tab and display api definition and operation.

Is there any custom project fork swagger-ui that meets my requirement?

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634281/list-of-swagger-ui-alternatives  
Also, you can do some form of layout customization here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/customization/custom-layout.md